# Is the Lego 8884 IR Receiver compatible with earlier IR Speed Remotes e.g. from set 7897?

Tags: trains, compatibility, city

I'm thinking of buying the new Train power function, e.g. 8884 IR Receiver, 88000 Battery Box, and 8879 IR Speed Remote. However I already have the set 7897, is the Speed Remote from this set compatible with 8884 IR Receiver ? Does anyone know ?
I think the train motor is compatible by the way, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Generalizing the question, are RC and PF compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think RC devices are not compatible with PF devices due using different IR protocols.

For instance, see [this forum thread](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=66077) for more explanation. Also [this cool site](http://www.holgermatthes.de/bricks/en/train-systems.php).

Summarizing,

- RC and PF can use the same rails
- RC and PF cannot use the same remote controllers
- RC and PF uses different engines:

  - RC places it in bogie (as 9v do)
  - PF places it in body

Comment: That about sums it up; in addition, note that the motor itself has a different connector, so you could still use it with the newer PF elements, but you'd need a [conversion cable](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=8886-1).

Answer (score 1):

You can only control PF IR receivers with the PF remote controls. These are the normal (8885) or the speed control (8879). With the speed remote control you can also choose different speeds. And yes, the train motor from 7897 is compatible with power functions, as long as you use a extension wire (acts like adapter from the old 9V-system to PF, 8886 or 8871).

You could also use a trick by controling a motor via the receiver from 7897, wich controls the PF remote control. But that´s a bit tricky, and I  haven`t found a way yet where you can actually control the speed stepwise :/